# Apache allow HTTPS with Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, .htaccess, ubuntu-18.04

I am setting up an UBUNTU 18.04 environment with Apache, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin etc.

I need to allow HTTPS connection for URL rewrites, currently HTTPS crash when I enter a 'pretty' URL

**HTTPS:**

If I access through HTTP `https://www.example.com` works, if I try to access `https://example.com/content/1` (pretty URL) the website crashes but if I try to access `https://www.example.com?page=content&id=1` everything works and the HTTPS connection works.

**HTTP:**

If I access through HTTP there are no problems I can access all domains e.g `http://example.com/user` and `http://example.com/content/1`.

I found different tutorials and guides and I've come to the conclusion that I need to edit the Virtual Hosts `.cfg` file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName <myip>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
        <Directory /var/www/html>
           DirectoryIndex index.php
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I think that I need to get these 2 parts

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
```

Where do I get `.crt` and `.key` files?

Do they have anything to do with SSL private/public keys? because these two files I have, but they do not have `.crt` and `.key` extensions?

Whole Config File

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    # Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName <myip>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
        <Directory /var/www/html>
           DirectoryIndex index.php
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&c=$2&d=$3&e=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&c=$2&d=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&c=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: "the website crash" - What's the error?

Comment: @MrWhite its unable to connect

Comment: Is it intentional that you wrote: "`https://example.com/content/1` **[no-www]** (pretty URL) the website crash but if I try to access `https://www.example.com?page=content&id=1` **[www]** everything works" - is the "www" subdomain significant here? (It would seem to be if the former is simply "failing to connect".) `ServerName <myip>` is incorrect. You should be using the same `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` that you are using in `<VirtualHost *:80>`. You also aren't enabling `FollowSymLinks` in the 443 vHost (which could be required for mod_rewrite to work in `.htaccess`).

Comment: Not an immediate concern, but you also aren't setting `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` in your 443 vHost either.

Comment: "If I access through HTTP `https://www.example.com` works" - should that state HTTP**S**?

Comment: @MrWhite no it has nothing to do with www/non www its just pretty urls that did not work in HTTPS... Tried to restart apache, it gave me an  error and i am not not able to start apache

Comment: "i am not not able to start apache" - If you are not able to start Apache then how are your non-pretty URLs working?!

Comment: No sorry, apache is working I was just messing with some configuration. the problem is still that the HTTP to https redirect of rewritten "pretty URLs" does not work